# Debian - Screen flashing and black bar scrolling down

Tags: debian, x-server

This has been driving me absolutely insane for the past 3 hours. I feel like shooting this computer right now.

After waiting about 3 hours for Debian to install, the graphics are completely borked. I can't identify anything on the screen.

There are a bunch of blue-grayish diamond shape things that are flashing on the screen, and a big horizontal black bar the scrolls down the screen continuously.

[image: Photo of screen]

Ctrl+Alt+[1-7] doesn't work, nor does Alt+[1-7]